# How to pass classOf[T] to method accepting A when T extends A?

Tags: scala

I have a method that is called in numerous places in my app:

```
def getCar(model: Model, data: Data[Any], clazz: Class[CarReference]): Either[ParsingError, ParsingResult] = {
  // Do some stuff...
  data match {
    case b: CarType =>
      Right(model.copy(carTypes = clazz.getConstructors.head.newInstance(b.id.toString).asInstanceOf[Bla] :: model.carTypes))
    case _ => Left(Parsing Error())
  }
}
```

Here, `carTypes` can be an instance of any class that extends `Bla`, such as:

```
sealed trait Bla

trait CarReference extends Bla {
  val id: String
}

case class SkodaCarReference(id: String) extends CarReference

case class VWCarReference(id: String) extends CarReference
```

After the `carTypes` list has been populated, I want to process its elements in a certain way depending on whether it is an instance of `SkodaCarReference` or `VWCarReference` (implemented via a trivial pattern matching).

The problem is, that I get a compile error, when calling this method:

```
def processSkoda(...): Unit = {
     // Do some stuff...
      getCar(model, data, classOf[SkodaCarReference)] <--- error
     // Do some stuff...
}

def processVW(...): Unit = {
     // Do some stuff...
      getCar(model, data, classOf[VWCarReference)] <--- error
     // Do some stuff...
}
```

The error:

```
    type mismatch;
     found   : Class[SkodaCarReference](classOf[SkodaCarReference])
     required: Class[CarReference]
    Note: SkodaCarReference <: CarReference, but Java-defined class Class is invariant in type T.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `def getCar[C <: CarReference](model: Model, data: Data[Any], clazz: Class[CarReference])` but .. 1. Using `Any` is quite a code smell, 2. Using runtime reflection can hardly be recommended

Comment: @cchantep Thanks for your help. 1. `Data` is a generated trait (i.e., I cannot change it). 2. I am not sure whether I even need runtime reflection. Basically, all I want to accomplish is to have a generic method and to pass classes (which extend `CarReference`) in order to dynamically create instances.

Comment: Otherwise, I would have to make several distinct methods for `SkodaCarReference`, `VWCarReference`, ... to instantiate the correct class, or?

Comment: And so? At least it would be check by the compiler and so safe, which is not the case with runtime reflection (as it can be guessed from the name ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`classOf[SkodaCarReference]` has type `Class[SkodaCarReference]`, which is not a subtype of `Class[CarReference]`. You could use either cchantep's answer or

```
def getCar(model: Model, data: Data[Any], clazz: Class[_ <: CarReference])
```

where `Class[_ <: CarReference]` can be read as `Class[some subtype of CarReference]`.

> I am not sure whether I even need runtime reflection.

> in order to dynamically create instances

Creating instances from a class requires runtime reflection; in your case `getConstructors` and `newInstance`.

> Otherwise, I would have to make several distinct methods for SkodaCarReference, VWCarReference, ... to instantiate the correct class, or?

No. You can pass the constructor as a function:

```
def getCar(model: Model, data: Data[Any], constructor: String => CarReference): Either[ParsingError, ParsingResult] = {
  // Do some stuff...
  data match {
    case b: CarType =>
      Right(model.copy(carTypes = constructor(b.id.toString).asInstanceOf[Bla] :: model.carTypes))
    case _ => Left(Parsing Error())
  }
}

// called as
getCar(model, data, new SkodaCarReference(_))
getCar(model, data, new VWCarReference(_))
```

Then you can't accidentally pass a class which doesn't have a suitable constructor, or which has several constructors and `getConstructors` doesn't return the one taking the `String` first.